# amalgamation of three measures

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X, Y, Z$ be three measurable (say, Radon) spaces, and let $\mu_{ab}, a, b \in \{X,Y,Z\}, a \neq b$ be three measures on spaces defined on respective spaces $a \times b$. Is it true that there exists a measure $\mu$ on $X\times Y \times Z$ such that $(p_{ab})_* \mu=\mu_{ab}$ for all pairs of distinct $a,b$? If yes, is it unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false. Consider $X = Y = Z = \mathbb{R}.$ Now take the measures:

- $\mu_{XY}$ as the product of two independent gaussian measures on $\mathbb{R}.$
- $\mu_{YZ}$ as the product of two independent exponential measures on $\mathbb{R}.$
- choose the last measure as you prefer.

Now suppose there exists a $\mu$ as asked.We would get: $$p_{Y*}(p_{XY*}(\mu)) =p_{Y*}(\mu) =  p_{Y*}(p_{YZ*}(\mu))$$ But we have on the l.h.s. a gaussian measure and on the right hand side an exponential measure. This is impossible.

It is quite intuitive that to get a measure on product spaces you need the projections to be consistent with each other.

Comment: you are right, of course. one has to require that $p_{X,*} \mu_{XY} = p_{X,*} \mu_{XZ}$ and so forth. what if one asks for this compatibility of measures $\mu_{XY}, \mu_{XZ}, \mu_{YZ}$, do you thing then the answer would be positive?

Answer (score 1):

Consistency of the marginals is not sufficient for existence if you want a positive measure.  Consider $X=Y=Z = \{0,1\}$ and suppose all $\mu_{a,b}(0,1) = \mu_{a,b}(1,0) = 1/2$, $\mu_{a,b}(0,0) = \mu_{a,b}(1,1) = 0$.  The marginals are all consistent with $\mu_a(0)=\mu_a(1) = 1/2$, but there is no possible positive measure because every configuration has at least two entries equal.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest counterexample to uniqueness (where the marginals are consistent) is the case where each of $X,Y,Z$ have two points.  Write $X = Y = Z = \{0,1\}$.

Consider tossing two independent fair coins.  Define random variables $U_1, U_2, U_3$.
Let $U_1$ be $1$ if the first coin is heads, otherwise $0$.
Let $U_2$ be $1$ if the second coin is heads, otherwise $0$.
Let $U_3$ be $1$ if the two coins agree, otherwise $0$.
Then each pair of these random variables is independent, but the triple is not independent.  The joint distribution of $(U_1, U_2, U_3)$ is your measure on $X \times Y \times Z$.  It is not the uniform measure.  But the three marginal distributions on $X \times Y, Y \times Z, Z \times X\;$ are all uniform.  And, of course, the uniform measure on $X \times Y \times Z$ has these same marginals.

[This is a standard exercise in elementary probability theory: a set of random variables may be pairwise independent without actually being independent.]